# Xcode проект с сторонним бинарным файлом в AppStore, как подписать, как добавить entitlements?

Tags: xcode, objective-c, macos, binary, sandbox

У меня проект с сторонним бинарником, который используется в проекте (копируется в ресурсы). При попытке добавить приложение в AppStore возникает ошибка.

> App Store Connect Operation Error. ERROR ITMS-90296: "App sandbox not
>   enabled. The following executables must include the
>   "com.apple.security.app-sandbox" entitlement with a Boolean value in
>   the entitlements property list: [] Refer to App Sandbox page at
>   https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ma/app-sandbox/ for more
>   information on sandboxing your app."

Если бинарник убрать, то приложение спокойно добавляется в AppStore, т.е. для основного приложения sandbox включен. 
Как добавить entitlements к стороннему бинарнику и как его подписать?